# how can I copy one file to multiple sub directories

Tags: nant

I'm trying to use nant because I thought it would be the easiest, but i'm open to any solution that works on windows xp.

I have the following folder structure

```
basefolder
    folder1
    folder2
        subfolder1
            code
                solutionname1
                     projectname.interface
                     projectname.simulation
                     projectname.testcase
                         bin
                             release
    folder3
    ...
    folderN
```

folder1 - folderN all have the same directory structure as folder2.  I want to copy a file to the release folder in each folderN.

I currently have the following nant script

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://nant.sf.net/release/0.90/nant.xsd" name="CopyDll" default="FileCopy">
  <property name="fileToCopy"
            value="C:\file.dll"
            overwrite="false"/>
  <property name="baseDirectory" value="${directory::get-current-directory()}" overwrite="false"/>
  <target name="FileCopy"
          description="Copies file to multiple directories">
    <foreach item="Folder"
             in="${baseDirectory}"
             property="foldername">
      <in>
        <items>
          <include name="**\**\**\*.TestCase\bin\Release"/>
        </items>
      </in>
      <do>
        <copy file="${fileToCopy}"
              todir="${foldername}"/>
        <echo message="Copied file to ${foldername}"/>
      </do>
    </foreach>   
  </target>
</project>
```

This copies file.dll to each folderN directory.
What am I doing wrong?
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had to change my foreach to look like this

```
    <foreach item="Folder"
             property="foldername">
      <in>
        <items>
          <include name="${baseDirectory}\**\*.TestCase\bin\Release"/>
        </items>
      </in>
      <do>
        <copy file="${fileToCopy}"
              todir="${foldername}"/>
        <echo message="Copied file to ${foldername}"/>
      </do>
    </foreach>
```